# PHP Session using WAMP Server

Tags: php

I'm trying PHP session where the user will input an Email in page 1 .
After they've entered , they'll be redirect to page 2 with the email displayed as the user.

Here's my page 1 PHP code looks like :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']= isset($_POST['email']) ;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

header('Location: http://localhost/page2');
}   
?>
<form method="post" action=""> 

Email: <input type="text" name="email"  value=""/> <br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> </form>
```

Page 2 :

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = (isset($_SESSION['email']));
echo $_SESSION['email'];
//print_r($_SESSION);
//var_dump($email);
?>
```

Problem:

The problem is , when I entered any random emails , it shows number 1 in page 2 when I echoed it.

Comment: isset is a boolean function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That' because you assign the return value of the function `isset()`!

So this should work for you:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
    $_SESSION['email']= $_POST['email'];
    header('Location: http://localhost/page2');
}
```

Also on your second page you assign it again which you don't have to! You have to check it like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['email']))
    echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

(BTW: I hope this is more an example: `header('Location: http://localhost/page2');` because you would have to add the file extension like: `header('Location: http://localhost/page2.php');`)

Comment: Up voted this because of the explanation. OP is assigning the return value of the `isset()` function to the variable, not the actual value. I assume he wanted something like this: `$_SESSION['email'] = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email']  : '';`

Answer (score 0):

The statement below assign TRUE or FALSE to the session variable as `isset()` returns boolean values not the string passed.

But, you need to assign the value to it.

Simply change:

```
$_SESSION['email']= isset($_POST['email']);
```

To

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $_SESSION['email']= $_POST['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Page 1

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    header('Location: http://localhost/page2');
}   
?>

<form method="post" action="http://localhost/page2"> 
Email: <input type="text" name="email"  value=""/> <br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
</form>
```

On Page 2

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['emai'];
echo $_SESSION['email'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Page 1

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
header('Location: http://localhost/page2');
}   
?>

<form method="post" action=""> 
Email: <input type="text" name="email"  value=""/> <br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Page 2

```
<?php
session_start();

//check if session exist
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
echo $_SESSION['email'];
}

?>
```